Custom Webform Element in Drupal: Radio Buttons with Score Input Field
I'm developing a custom Drupal module to add a new form element to the Webform module, which allows users to assign a score to each option in a radio button field. I’m new to Drupal development and would appreciate any guidance on what I might be doing wrong.
Objective:
To create a custom Webform element where each radio option can have an additional score input field.
Here is the code for webform_custom_choice.module:
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_webform_element_info_alter().
 */
function webform_custom_choice_webform_element_info_alter(array &$element_info) {
  $element_info['choice_with_score'] = [
    'class' => 'Drupal\webform_custom_choice\Plugin\WebformElement\ChoiceWithScore',
    'label' => t('Choice with Score'),
    'description' => t('Adds a radio button with an extra score field per option.'),
  ];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_webform_element_presave().
 */
function webform_custom_choice_webform_element_presave(&$element) {
  if (isset($element['#score'])) {
    foreach ($element['#options'] as $key => &$option) {
      $element['#score'][$key] = $element['#score'][$key] ?? 0;
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_webform_submission_presave().
 */
function webform_custom_choice_webform_submission_presave(\Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission $webform_submission) {
  $data = $webform_submission->getData();

  if (isset($data['choice_with_score'])) {
    $choice_value = $data['choice_with_score'];
    $element = $webform_submission->getWebform()->getElement('choice_with_score');
    $score = isset($element['#score'][$choice_value]) ? $element['#score'][$choice_value] : 0;

    $data['choice_with_score'] = ['value' => $choice_value, 'score' => $score];
    $webform_submission->setData($data);
  }
}

Here is the code for ChoiceWithScore.php:
php
<?php

namespace Drupal\webform_custom_choice\Plugin\WebformElement;

use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElement\Radios;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Provides a 'choice_with_score' element.
 *
 * @WebformElement(
 *   id = "choice_with_score",
 *   label = @Translation("Choice with Score"),
 *   description = @Translation("Provides a radio button element with an additional score field for each option."),
 *   category = @Translation("Choices"),
 * )
 */
class ChoiceWithScore extends Radios {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function prepare(array &$element, ?\Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission = null) {
    parent::prepare($element, $webform_submission);

    if (isset($element['#options'])) {
      foreach ($element['#options'] as $key => &$value) {
        if (isset($element['#score'][$key])) {
          $value .= ' (Score: ' . $element['#score'][$key] . ')';
        } else {
          $element['#score'][$key] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getDefaultProperties() {
    $properties = parent::getDefaultProperties();
    $properties['states_wrapper'] = [];
    $properties['id'] = 'choice_with_score';
    $properties['composite'] = FALSE;
    $properties['multiline'] = FALSE;
    $properties['score'] = [];

    return $properties;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function settingsForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array $complete_form) {
    $form = parent::settingsForm($form, $form_state, $complete_form);

    $options = $form_state->getValue(['properties', 'options']) ?: $this->getElementOptions();
    $scores = $form_state->getValue(['properties', 'score']) ?: $this->getElementScore();

    foreach ($options as $key => $label) {
      $form['score'][$key] = [
        '#type' => 'number',
        '#title' => $this->t('Score for @option', ['@option' => $label]),
        '#default_value' => isset($scores[$key]) ? $scores[$key] : 0,
        '#description' => $this->t('Specify a score for this option.'),
      ];
    }

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * Helper function to get scores for each option.
   */
  private function getElementScore() {
    return $this->getElementProperty('score', []);
  }
}



Issues:

I can't see the extra score input fields when creating a webform.
When I test the form, the question doesn’t display, and when I submit the form, I can only see the selected option without the score.

What I might be missing or doing wrong?
